# PHP Count characters inside title tag

Tags: php, count, strlen

I'm trying to count the text inside my title tag. But it doesn't seem to work. I've tried count(), strlen() etc. For example:

```
<title>Count me!</title>
```

When i use strlen() i get this error:

```
strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

When i use count u just get 2. I think it counts the title tags inside my file.

Controller:

```
$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
$count = strlen($title);
```

Index:

```
{{$count}}
```

Comment: `strlen()` will not give expected results with multibyte encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$title_tag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
foreach($tital_tag as $title){
$title_length = strlen($title->nodeValue);
}
```

You need to loop through title tags ... It doesn't mean you have multiple tags . Dom simply return object which need to be accessed
 and then you get length of title

Comment: You are the man! It works but the only problem is that it outputs this: "69 12". The 69 is correct but i don't want to output the 12. How would i do that? I'll also read the documentation again.

Comment: show screenshots .. i don't think it should return like that

Comment: It was a problem of the website i've tried. I've tried other websites and that worked perfect! Thank you my good sir!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object, not a string.

You need to iterate over the elements in the list with a `foreach` loop and retrieve the length of each node's value.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative using jquery you can count the character as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var title = $(document).prop('title').length; 
    console.log(title);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve the result doing just that because what the getElementsByTagName() function does is return "A NodeList object, representing a collection of elements with the specified tag name.".

ie. if you called it on a ul  tag it would give you a collection of li tags within that ul.

You could try this though;

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Heello</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML.length;//get the length of the first title tag
  alert(text);//text no contains the length of characters within the title tag
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The elements in the returned collection are sorted as they appear in the source code.